# Vhdl Snake - how to automate tail implementation

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I've been currently implementing the snake game in vhdl for Spartan3e.

I have already written a part that draws a cell square on VGA screen and makes it possible to move it around the square.

The problem is with tail implementation - as far I have manually added another cell segment to my snake but I would like to automate it (as for example in java simply making the queue with the cells and setting the positiong of the next cell as the cell before). I do not know how to write such a complex function in vhdl.

Here is my code:

```
 begin
   process (clk, reset, endOfGame)
   begin
      if reset='1' or endOfGame=true then

         ball_y_reg <=  to_unsigned(231,10);
         ball_x_reg <=  to_unsigned(311,10);
         ball_x_reg_cell<=to_unsigned(231,10);
         ball_y_reg_cell<=to_unsigned(311,10);
-- velocity after reset schould be none
         x_delta_reg <= ("0000000000");
         y_delta_reg <= ("0000000000");


      elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then
         ball_x_reg_cell<=ball_x_next_cell;
         ball_y_reg_cell<=ball_y_next_cell;
         ball_x_reg <= ball_x_next;
         ball_y_reg <= ball_y_next;
         x_delta_reg <= x_delta_next;
         y_delta_reg <= y_delta_next;
      end if;
   end process;

   pix_x <= unsigned(pixel_x);
   pix_y <= unsigned(pixel_y);

   -- refr_tick: 1-clock tick asserted at start of v-sync
   -- i.e., when the screen is refreshed (60 Hz)
   refr_tick <= '1' when (pix_y=481) and (pix_x=0) else
                '0';

   ----------------------------------------------
   -- pixel within wall
   wall_on <=
      '1' when ((WALL_X_LEFTSIDE_L<=pix_x) and (pix_x<=WALL_X_LEFTSIDE_R)) or ((WALL_X_RIGHTSIDE_L<=pix_x) and (pix_x<=WALL_X_RIGHTSIDE_R)) or ((WALL_Y_UPSIDE_U<=pix_y) and (pix_y<=WALL_Y_UPSIDE_D)) or ((WALL_Y_DOWNSIDE_U<=pix_y) and (pix_y<=WALL_Y_DOWNSIDE_D)) else
      '0';
   -- wall rgb output
   wall_rgb <= "001"; -- blue



   ----------------------------------------------   

   -- square ball

   ball_x_l <= ball_x_reg;
   ball_y_t <= ball_y_reg;
   ball_x_r <= ball_x_l + BALL_SIZE - 1;
   ball_y_b <= ball_y_t + BALL_SIZE - 1;

   ball_x_l_cell <= ball_x_reg_cell;
   ball_y_t_cell <= ball_y_reg_cell;
   ball_x_r_cell <= ball_x_l_cell + BALL_SIZE - 1;
   ball_y_b_cell <= ball_y_t_cell + BALL_SIZE - 1;


   --tail


   -- pixel within squared ball
   sq_ball_on <=
      '1' when ((ball_x_l<=pix_x) and (pix_x<=ball_x_r) and
               (ball_y_t<=pix_y) and (pix_y<=ball_y_b)) 
               or
               ((ball_x_l_cell<=pix_x) and (pix_x<=ball_x_r_cell) and
               (ball_y_t_cell<=pix_y) and (pix_y<=ball_y_b_cell)) 
               else
      '0';

   ball_x_next <= ball_x_reg + x_delta_reg
                     when refr_tick='1' else
                  ball_x_reg ;
   ball_y_next <= ball_y_reg + y_delta_reg
                     when refr_tick='1' else
                  ball_y_reg ;

  ball_x_next_cell <= ball_x_reg - BALL_SIZE when refr_tick='1' and CURRENT_DIRECTION = DIR_RIGHT 
                     else ball_x_reg + BALL_SIZE when refr_tick='1' and CURRENT_DIRECTION = DIR_LEFT
                     else ball_x_reg when refr_tick='1'
                     else ball_x_reg_cell;

  ball_y_next_cell <=      ball_y_reg - BALL_SIZE when refr_tick='1' and CURRENT_DIRECTION = DIR_UP 
                      else ball_y_reg + BALL_SIZE when refr_tick='1' and CURRENT_DIRECTION = DIR_DOWN
                      else ball_y_reg  when refr_tick='1'
                      else ball_y_reg_cell;

   -- new bar y-position
   process(ball_y_reg, ball_y_b, ball_y_t, refr_tick, btn, ball_x_reg ,ball_x_r, ball_x_l, x_delta_reg, y_delta_reg)
   begin
      x_delta_next <= x_delta_reg;
      y_delta_next <= y_delta_reg;


      if refr_tick='1' then
         if btn(1)='1' and ball_y_b<(MAX_Y-1-BALL_SIZE) then
            if CURRENT_DIRECTION /= DIR_UP then

               CURRENT_DIRECTION <= DIR_DOWN;
               y_delta_next <= BALL_V_P; -- move down
               x_delta_next <= (others=>'0');

            end if;
         elsif btn(0)='1' and ball_y_t > BALL_SIZE then
            if CURRENT_DIRECTION /= DIR_DOWN then

               CURRENT_DIRECTION <= DIR_UP;
               y_delta_next <= BALL_V_N; -- move up
               x_delta_next <= (others=>'0');

            end if;  
         elsif btn(2)='1' and ball_x_r<(MAX_X-1-BALL_SIZE) then
            if CURRENT_DIRECTION /= DIR_LEFT then

               CURRENT_DIRECTION <= DIR_RIGHT;
               x_delta_next <= BALL_V_P;
               y_delta_next <= (others=>'0');

            end if;   
         elsif btn(3)='1' and ball_x_l > BALL_SIZE then
            if CURRENT_DIRECTION /= DIR_RIGHT then

               CURRENT_DIRECTION <= DIR_LEFT;
               x_delta_next <= BALL_V_N;
               y_delta_next <= (others=>'0');

            end if;  
         end if;

      if ball_x_l < WALL_X_LEFTSIDE_R or ball_y_t < WALL_Y_UPSIDE_D  or ball_y_b > WALL_Y_DOWNSIDE_U or ball_x_r > WALL_X_RIGHTSIDE_L then
         endOfGame <= true;
         CURRENT_DIRECTION <= IDLE;
      else
         endOfGame <= false;
         end if;

      end if;
   end process;
```

"Ball x next cell " parts is manually added second cell.

I have been searching through topics containing similiar problem but it is not covering it in vhdl.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't VHDL - don't get lost in the language differences between VHDL and Java - these are trivial here.

The problem is synthesisability - you need a conceptual design that can be represented in hardware.

You say your Java implementation uses a queue - this will be based on a linked list, with nodes (segments) dynamically allocated, and referenced via pointers. And in fact you could straightforwardly translate that into VHDL, using access types, new and deallocate, and so on. You'd have to implement the details yourself, while there might be a convenient library, i.e. class, in Java. But that's mere detail.

Don't go down that road - access types and especially dynamic allocation aren't synthesisable - you can't normally generate and free chunks of hardware to a running system...

(But you might do that if you wanted to run an existing Snake in a simulator, in parallel with the synthesisable version, to compare their results and verify the synthesisable one matches the already proven software version. If you need a high-reliability Snake designed to military, aerospace or safety critical requirements, you'll need this step.)

You need a different mindset for hardware design, based on knowing what is physically realisable, and how to translate concepts into that.

So, instead you need to consider how you might implement a snake segment before the system starts, and only turn it on when you need it. Then consider how to create as many as you'll ever need before the system starts.

For example a segment might need to know its colour and its X/Y coordinates and some other stuff, like, is it on/visible yet. How might you represent all that?

You might decide, having played the game and reached 50 segments, that 100 is enough to win the game.

Now, records and fixed size arrays are absolutely synthesisable.

That might get you started...

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I am aware of limitations in vhdl language, however I'm asking about implementation tips. I know i have to use array of records which contains currect and next location, direction, visibility. The question is, how can i iterate through array of records as concurrent statement as I do currently with my one cell ( segment ). I need to do such operation becouse of animation which i have to face with.

Comment: That depends on your performance needs. A simple loop can iterate over the array's range in a single clock cycle, but will prevent the array from being implemented as BlockRam and may generate HUGE hardware. You're probably looking at a state machine, and iterating over one cell per clock cycle. That depends on your exact requirements.